# AngularJS - DropDown Menu not working correctly with ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using Foundation 5 to create a Drop-Down Navigation. The Navigation is creating with ng-repeat, the input comming from a `JSON` file.

Basically all is working fine, but when I have three levels on my bar and i want to open the last level, I want to click on the second level that the menu is not disappears when the mouse is leaving. In the standard code from foundation this is working fine, but why it is not working with `ng-repeat` ?

I have created a Plunker - First my Navigation Menu and afterwards the Standard Menu from Foundation, where you can click on a sublevel and the menu doesn't appear when the mouse is leaving.

https://plnkr.co/edit/gZCtMrMRXOD0DnjMqId5?p=preview

This is my Code:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">             
      <ul class="left">
        <li class=""></li>
        <!-- Start Navigation 1. Level -->
        <li ng-class="{'has-dropdown':navigation.type === 'Sub', 'nav_button':navigation.type === 'Main'}" ng-repeat="navigation in nav.links">
          <a ng-if="navigation.type == 'Main'" href="{{navigation.link1}}" class="">{{navigation.name}}</a>
          <a ng-if="navigation.type == 'Sub'" href="#" class="">{{navigation.name}}</a>

          <!-- Start Navigation 2. Level -->
          <ul ng-if="navigation.type == 'Sub'" class="dropdown">             
            <li ng-class="{'has-dropdown':subitem.type === 'Sub', 'nav_button':subitem.type === 'Main'}" ng-repeat="subitem in navigation.subitems">
              <a ng-if="subitem.type == 'Main'" href="{{subitem.link1}}" class="">{{subitem.name2}}</a>
              <a ng-if="subitem.type == 'Sub'" href="#" class="">{{subitem.name2}}</a>

              <!-- Start Navigation 3. Level -->
              <ul ng-if="subitem.type == 'Sub'" class="dropdown">             
                <li ng-repeat="subitem in subitem.subitems2"><a href="{{subitem.link}}">{{subitem.name3}}</a></li>
              </ul> 
            </li>
          </ul> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Strange is, when I set the option `'data-options="is_hover: false"'`, its working - but the Hover effect is necessary in my Case.

Anybody has a Suggestion for me to solve that ?

Comment: I don't understand, your plunker appears to be working.

Comment: In the first Menu (my menu), when you open 'Menu1' -> 'Sublink2' and click on it, it disappear when you leave the mouse. In the standard foundation menu its possible. When you open 'Main Item 4' -> 'Has Dropdown Level 1' and click on it, it still open when you leave the mouse. Do you know what i mean ?